# jquery toggle and datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with data generated from the DB and published with Jquery Datatables. So far all works.

Each row has a checkbox, which can be toggled, that triggers an update to the DB. All rows on the first page (50) of the dataTable, work nicely. Once it gets to the second page (or use the search) the code doesn't work anymore.

The HTML code in the table. The ID is incremental and is unique per input.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="manual_86">
```

At the bottom of the page, this piece of code is running (stripped out the rest of the code for example purposes)

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        console.log("update");
});
```

I'm struggling to find out why this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your checkboxes are created dynamically when you loads the page 2, or when you make a search. The checkboxes don't exist when the listener is created.

Assuming your checkboxes are wrapped in a static container (not created dynamically), you can use this snippet to create the event listener. You just have to replace "staticParent" by the selector of the static container.

```
$(staticParent).on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(){
    console.log("update");
});
```

If you are using an old version of jQuery, you can use the `live()` function